# Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'. in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, render

I was trying to delete an individual row from jQuery data-table based on the `userID` by making the AJAX call from my jQuery and then calling my action method `DisableUser(int userID)`. When I'm redirected to the view, I get an error.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('#usersList').on('click', 'button[id^="delete_"]', function () {
    var userId = this.id.replace("delete_", "");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"@Html.Action("DisableUser","Admin")",
        data: { UserID: userId },
        success: function (response) {
            // Handle success response if needed
            console.log('User deleted successfully');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Handle error response if needed
            console.error('Error deleting user', error);
        }
    });
});
```

`#userList` is the id of the jQuery `DataTable`.

Here is my action method in my `AdminController` :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisableUser(int UserID)
{
    if (UserID != 0 && UserID > 0)
    {
        int result = _helper.DisableUser(UserID);

        switch (result)
        {
            case 1:
                TempData["SaveMessage"] = "User disabled successfully";
                break;

            case -1:
                TempData["SaveMessage"] = "Error disabling user";
                break;

            default:
                TempData["SaveMessage"] = "Unknown error";
                break;
        };
    }

    var users = RetrieveUserList();

    return View("AllUsersData", users);
}
```

`RetrieveUserList()` is fetching the data and will be sent in JSON format. It is bound to my `User` model class.

`AllUsersData` is the JSON format view for jQuery `DataTable`.

When I'm redirected to the view, I get this error:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

on this Line :

```
url:"@Html.Action("DisableUser", "Admin")",
```

This is followed by 2 inner exceptions:

> HttpException: Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information

> HttpException: A public action method 'DisableUser' was not found on controller 'SiteAdministrator1._1._0.Controllers.AdminController'

What is the main issue I am facing here - any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to use [`@Url.Action()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-urlhelper-action(system-string-system-string)) instead of `@Html.Action()` to generate the correct URL.

When you are using the `@Html.Action()` here the MVC Razor engine is trying to find the `DisableUser()` action method with the `[HttpGet]` attribute and after not finding it throws the `HttpException: A public action method 'DisableUser' was not found on controller`.

Comment: To add:  you (OP) would not get the error for `url : '@Html.Action(..)'` - just a terrible url (ie the full `<a href=...` except for the fact that your (OPs) action has `[HttpPost]` - as it's limited to POST only, you can't generate an anchor (`<a>`) to it, so you get the exception rather than just a badly formatted "url".

Comment: @freedomn-m: You are right. The exception is raised earlier than the  HTML is generated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Jackdaw , It really helped and also the exception and the reason behind it . :)